# Can I use browserlink on a separate device?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Browserlink is a pretty cool feature in visual studio 2013, but I'm developing a mobile website and would love to have my pages open on an android and an iphone, and have browserlink refresh those too.

Is this possible? I have read that browserlink only enables on request from localhost by default.